# Get current page in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In vue I handle the code :

```
<b-pagination
  :total-rows="props.total"
  first-number
  last-number
  align="right"
  prev-class="prev-item"
  next-class="next-item"
  class="mt-1 mb-0"
  @input="changePage"
  >
</b-pagination>
```

Here's an example pagination:

> << 1 2 3 4 >>

```
methods: {
    changePage() {
         //get current page
    }
}
```

Now I want to get current page in methods, please give me ideas, thanks.

Comment: do your page base on router path? `computed: {currentPage(){return this.$router.query.page;}}` may work

Comment: url page `http://localhost.loca/product`

Comment: could you please show more code of this componet? especially the code get data from api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using b-pagination , please refer to this link.
[bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination)

```
<script>
      export default {
        data() {
          return {
            perPage: 3,
            currentPage: 1,
            items: [
              { id: 1, first_name: 'Fred', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
              { id: 2, first_name: 'Wilma', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
              { id: 3, first_name: 'Barney', last_name: 'Rubble' },
              { id: 4, first_name: 'Betty', last_name: 'Rubble' },
              { id: 5, first_name: 'Pebbles', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
              { id: 6, first_name: 'Bamm Bamm', last_name: 'Rubble' },
              { id: 7, first_name: 'The Great', last_name: 'Gazzoo' },
              { id: 8, first_name: 'Rockhead', last_name: 'Slate' },
              { id: 9, first_name: 'Pearl', last_name: 'Slaghoople' }
            ]
          }
        },
        computed: {
          rows() {
            return this.items.length
          }
        }
      }
    </script>

    <b-pagination
      v-model="currentPage"
      :total-rows="rows"
      :per-page="perPage"
      aria-controls="my-table"
    ></b-pagination>
```

currentPage is in your v-Model and consist with the name in b-table ":current-page".

```
 <p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>   

<b-table id="my-table"
      :items="items"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      small
    ></b-table>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i want to get current page dynamic and not static

Comment: set  v-model="currentPage" in your html , it is current page what user clicked.